# Use Design Pattern with PlayFramework

Tags: design-patterns, playframework

I'm planning to implement **Observer** pattern and **Decorator** pattern in a play application. Now, is there any convention for package naming? Where can I store my **Interfaces**, **Abstract Classes**.

I've searched for it but didn't get any suitable result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [post](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2011/12/design-patterns-series-5-observer.html) and this [post](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2011/11/design-patterns-series-3-decorator.html)

Comment: @AmirIsmail I think you didn't get my problem. I'm not asking about the design pattern implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your controllers, models and views are in the correct packages (see "The MVC application mode" in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/main), you can have any other packages that you want.  If you want something a bit more traditional, you can do something like

```
app 
  |-controllers 
  |-models 
  |-views 
  |-com
      |-mycompany
          |-whatever
```